# Powershell close button

Tags: powershell-4.0

I skripted a gui but my close button wont work
this are the forms
$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,300) # Window size
$Form.text                       = "Daniels Programm :)"    # window name

```
    $Form.StartPosition              = 'CenterScreen'  # specifies where the window should start
    #$Form.Topmost                    = $true  # Opens on top of other windows
    $Form.SizeGripStyle              = "Hide" # Fenster vergrößerung
    $Form.FormBorderStyle            = "Fixed3D" # Fenster vergrößerung
    #$Form.Add_FormClosing({
        # Add your code to handle the form closing event here
        #$Form.Dispose()
        #$script:value= 0
    #})
```

Comment: Can you please ensure the code is all formatted correctly. It looks like you've left some of the code outside of the code block in the main text.